# Run google script when specific cell has specific number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet called 'Admin' where I created a drop down with 4 options. Upon selecting the drop down, the 'trigger' column (3) will display a number.

[image]

In scripts, I have 4 scripts written and tested, but I want these to run based on the value displayed in the 'Trigger' column above:

[image]

Could anyone help me write this script, as I have tried numerous scripts but cannot seem to get anywhere close?

The sheet id is:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1doHHOSc3GkMX5jVayU63-PDXQ1Q4s4CepbMW6uXS3DY/edit?usp=sharing

My thanks in advance,

Brendon

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you for editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to run the function of the function name corresponding to the cell "C2" of the sheet "Admin".

  - For example, the value of cell "C2" is `1`, you want to run the function of `One()`.

In your case, how about using the OnEdit event trigger? But from your script, I think that it is required to use the OnEdit event trigger as the installable trigger.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor and [install the OnEdit event trigger to the function of `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Admin" && range.getA1Notation() == "A2") {
    var functions = {1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three, 4: Four};
    functions[range.offset(0, 2).getValue()]();
  }
}
```

- By above settings, when you change the dropdown list of the cell "A2" on the sheet "Admin", the function corresponding to the value of cell "C2" is run.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your functions of `One`, `Two`, `Three` and `Four` work fine. Please be careful this.
- When you modified the function names you want to run, please also modify `var functions = {1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three, 4: Four};`.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

### Added:

When you want to directly run the function of `installedOnEdit` with the script editor, at first, please check the following points.

In this case, it is required to fix the cell for using the function. So in your case, it supposes that the cell of "C2" on the sheet of "Admin" are always used. When you use other cells, please modify the following script for your situation. Please be careful this.

#### Modified script:

```
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var functions = {1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three, 4: Four};
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Admin");
  var value = sheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  functions[value]();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Tanaike. I installed it and ran the Trigger, but even if I run it manually I get this flag:  TypeError: Cannot read property Range of undefined (line 2).  Also should the Notation range (line 4) not be C2 as opposed to A2, seeing as C2 is the cell that changes each time A2 is selected?

Comment: Thanks lamblichus, I have done so. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: When using the sheet and triggering the script, I get a 'TypeError: e.range is not a function' alert. What would you guys suggest I change in Line 2 to correct?

Comment: @Iamblichus Thank you for your always support.

Comment: @Rugbycology Analytics Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I also think that the reason of your issue is that you directly run the function of `installedOnEdit` with the script editor. This has already been mentioned by Iamblichus. From your question, I proposed to use the OnEdit event trigger. For this, I used the event object. But when you want to use the function by directly running with the script editor, please confirm the added script in my answer. If I misunderstood your additional request, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks so much for this. I just ran the trigger as suggested and it works like a charm. Really appreciate the effort. Thank you Lamblichus also for your feedback.

Comment: @Rugbycology Analytics Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Guys I change cells in my sheet via Appsheet (on mobile phone), and find that each time any Tab is altered, it still triggers this function. I have tried setting the trigger as On Edit and On Change, but it keeps triggering each time any change is made to the entire sheet, not just the Tab "Admin".  Do I need to alter the script to specify?

Comment: @Rugbycology Analytics We would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. And also, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike understood. Thanks for letting me know and helping me get to grips with the procedure. I really appreciate it mate!

Comment: @Rugbycology Analytics Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks mate, I have tagged you into new question:  Avoid Google Script trigger each time a sheet is edited